# How to concatenate a list of strings in cmd?

Tags: list, cmd, concatenation, list-comprehension

Consider the one-liner of:

```
for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @echo %s
```

if I could define an empty string then:

```
set "var=empty" & for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @set "var=%var%, %s"
```

wold give me what I want. I tried the `set "var=0:~1"` thing from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1123684/588662):

```
set "var=0:~1" & for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @set "var=%var%, %s"
```

but it does not work. What I want to have in the end is a string of `str1, str2, str3` to be `echo`ed.

**P.S.** I am aware of the `for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @(@Echo|@Set /p="%A, ")` solution, but it does not behave the way I want. basically it prints multiple times to the stdout omiting the new-line, instead once which I require. I'm trying to use this command inside a `unig_g("...")` inside Scilab/ScicosLab which prints empty for that reason.

Comment: Since you are trying to do this as a one liner from the command prompt you need to enable delayed expansion when executing the commands. `cmd /V:on`. Then you need to reference the variable as `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

Comment: @Squashman could you be kind to elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish requires the use of delayed variable expansion.  In a batch file you would normally turn this on with a `SETLOCAL` command but since you are using the command line you need to execute `cmd.exe` and use the appropriate option to turn delayed expansion on.

```
cmd /V:ON /C "set "var=" & (for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @IF DEFINED var (@set "var=!var!, %s") else (set "var=%s")) & @echo !var!"
```

Comment: amazing. right to the point. Thanks a lot. FYI  the equivalent command in Scilab/Scicoslab is `unix_g("cmd /V:ON /C '"set '"var='" & (for %s in (str1 str2 str3) do @IF DEFINED var (@set '"var=!var!, %s'") else (s
 ans  =r=%s'")) & @echo !var!'"")`

Comment: One issue with this solution is that it returns `!var!` if the list empty. Any solution to this?

Comment: @Foad, so what do you think you could do to resolve that?  Hint: it is already in another part of the code I gave you.